# jpa OneToMany relation on dedicated parameter/column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I have table customer with parameters:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    public Long id_crm;
    public String City;
    public String Country;
```

and second table where I store some contact information.

```
@Entity
public class CustomerContact {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  public Role role;
  public Department department;
  public Long customer_id_crm
}
```

The second table is obtained from external crm app so I've added column `id_crm` for relation as foreign key.

I would like to make relation between those 2 entities on column:
`Customer.id_crm` and `CustomerContact.customer_id_crm`

The sql query for that will look like this:

```
Select * FROM Customer 
Join CustomerContact 
on Customer.id_crm=CustomerContact.customer_id_crm
```

Can I even achieve this with jpa? If so? How to do this?

Comment: Are you using composite key or simple key, I am posting the code to make relations. I am using my code for demo, not yours, check the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: What are you looking for? The mappings? What is the relationship from Customer to Customer Contact, one-to-one, one-to-many?

Comment: There isn't yet any relation. I am about to do this. But I have to use different column as foreign key in Contact table.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
session.createQuery("select c, cc from Customer c, CustomerContact cc where c.id_crm = cc.customer_id_crm")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the person class which has relationship one to many with canvas :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{


    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "person_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq_gen",sequenceName = "person_seq")
    private int id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person1",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Canvas> canvas1 = new HashSet<Canvas>();

    public Set<Canvas> getCanvas1() {
        return canvas1;
    }

    public void setCanvas1(Set<Canvas> canvas1) {

        this.canvas1 = canvas1;
    }
}
```

Canvas model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "canvas")
public class Canvas {

    @Id
    @Column(name="canvasid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "canvas_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "canvas_gen",sequenceName = "canvas_seq")
    private int canvasid;

 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id",nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore 
    private Person person1;

    public Person getPerson1() {
        return person1;
    }

    public void setPerson1(Person person1) {
        this.person1 = person1;
    }

    public int getPerson1id(){
        return this.person1.getId();
    }
}
```

Here is DAOImpl when you want to add a canvas :

```
public void addCanvas(Canvas canvas, Person person) {
        int id = person.getId();
        if( session == null) {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        }else {
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        Person person1 = (Person) session.get(Person.class,id);
        person.getCanvas1().add(canvas);
        canvas.setPerson1(person1);
        session.merge(canvas);
        session.flush();

    }
```

And I also have a method similar to your query :

```
public List<Canvas> listCanvasPerson(Person person) {
       int id = person.getId();
        if(session == null){
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        } else{
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }

        Query query = session.createQuery("from Canvas as c where c.person1.id=:id order by c.canvasnumber");
        query.setParameter("id",id);
        List<Canvas> canvasList = query.list();
```

Hope this helps, If I have made a mistake somewhere, let me know. please understand I am using a simple key, not a composite key.

Comment: Session is not JPA. The question is about JPA